# Resolve generic return type of method at runtim

Tags: java, generics, reflection

In a situation where the generic return type of a method only depends on the types of the input parameters (not on the class type parameters), how can I resolve the generic type to the actual type given a concrete list of parameters?

Let's say I have a method like this

```
public <T,S extends T> T doSomething(T input, S derivedInput)
```

and at Runtime I have a Method object `m` representing this method as well as some parameter objects `x` and `y` so that I can invoke the method with reflection

```
Object returnval = m.invoke(instance,Object[]{x,y});
```

Because the return type is determined by the types of the inputs and given that I know the actual types of `x` and `y` at runtime, I should be able to figure out at runtime what the type of `returnval` actually is, or at least a more specific superclass of the actual type than Object. In the example, I would expect there to be a way to automatically infer the class `x.getClass()` from `m`, `x` and `y`, assuming of course that `x` and `y` really satisfy the type constraint in the method definition, but ideally I would also be able to tell at runtime if they violate it.

Now I know that there is `Method#getGenericReturnType` and `Method#getGenericParameterTypes`, but I could not figure out how to use those to make the inference I want. I also know that this won't work if there is a type parameter of the class involved since those get erased. So I won't be able to resolve the T in `T List<T>.get(int)` given only a list and an integer. But if the return type is only dependent on the parameter types, I think it should be possible.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? What do you expect as the result of what you are currently trying?

Comment: The Java implementation of Generics employs type-erasure so you should not be relying on the generic type at runtime.  The benefits of generics mainly manifest at development/compile time.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html